# Links not clickable behind fixed position div using css clip

Tags: css

I am using fixed positions elements along side the css property `clip` to make a cool scrolling / paging effect.

This all works great but my issue is that I cannot click my links.

I can see that the fixed elements are overlaying each other which is causing the issue but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

I have tried changing `z-index` values on the containers and the anchor tag with no luck.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ukyrbc0/

If anyone can help that would be amazing!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured it out, but I cannot really explain it.

The first thing to do is to remove `pointer-events: none` so thanks to @manhatmanich for spotting that one.

This makes the first link clickable but not the rest, it looks like a z-index issue but changing the z-index values does not work.

So while playing around I tried removing the position absolute from the anchor tag and BOOM, all links clickable.

You can see a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9ukyrbc0/10/

I honestly don't understand how this fixes the problem but it does!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is within .fixed-container:

```
.fixed-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none; <-----
}



pointer-events: none;
```

Pointer Events are not triggered at all within that container ... thus links are not active.

more on this here ...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: This for coming back so quickly, unfortunately pointer-events does not have enough browser support.

Comment: take pointer-events: none; out of the code and the links will work!

Comment: Taking out `pointer-events` makes the first link work, but the rest do not work

Comment: also why do you use backface-visibility? I also see no 'clip' property that you are using ...

Comment: All the links point to google.com, so make them differently and you will see that they will work, at least for FF 35.0 tested!

Comment: I am using Chrome 39. The `backface-visibility` is for smooth scrolling and the `clip` is on the class `.innerContent`

Comment: I see. Ok but the links work, don't they? try here http://jsfiddle.net/9ukyrbc0/6/

Comment: Nope it does not work, I now get a version where the 2nd, 3rd and 4th pain does not show it's content.

Comment: Ok I just tested with chrome, it is all messed up. So it is a chrome specific thing, havn't tested with IE cause I am on linux

Comment: I have found a solution I think which works if you take the `position: absolute` off of the anchor tag, but replicating this onto my actual code base does not work.

Comment: ok great! Then just answer your own question when you are done! I am curious.

Comment: Perfect! worked for me. I added the pointer-events:none to the fixed element and now the links on the page work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, the code given here without the `pointer-events: none;` worked for me. The only issue is that I also had links in my fixed position element and now those links don't work.

Comment: Hey guys just figured how to do this with out all the complicated bs, you don't need the above code at all. Simply go to the specific <a> tag that holds the uncilck-able link and add the following <a style="position: relative;">  changing the anchors position to relative will solve your problem with out any hassle!

Comment: Very interesting, can you provide a working example / jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a floating action button with poistion-fixed bootstrap class added that did not work. It worked by just adding z-index:1 to its styles.